# c++ - cin word to char array, each input word display all words.

Tags: c++, arrays, char

1.
Create global char array name inputData and size 100- input word
create dynamic array which had size = input word;

2.
add dynamic array which stock pointers to all words.input new word effect show all words. if array is too small, double array size.

So I now how do first array , create array and input in loop, but I don't now how add word to array instead overwrite and then show all words. Any help?
Maybe I just do not understand this task.

```
#include <iostream>;
#include <string.h>;
#include <stdio.h>
char *inputData= new char[100];

using namespace std;

int main(){
//  cin>>::inputData;
//char* tablica2= new char (strlen(inputData));


cout<<"how many words"<<endl;
int input;
cin>>input;
int temp=0;
int len=0;
char *tab1= new char[input];
for(int i=0;i<input;i++){
    cout<<" enter word "<<i+1<<endl;
    char* tem2= new char[20];
    cin>>::inputData;
    len=len+strlen(::inputData);

    cout<<len;
   // int temp= temp+ strlen(::inputData);
    //cout<<::inputData[temp];
   // *(inputData+i)=*tem;
}
```

Comment: Since you're dealing with old C-style strings, the [`strcat`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcat) function might be useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I have understand what you want to do, but maybe you could use the ostrstream class to solve a part of your problem:

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <strstream.h>
using namespace std;
main(){

char buf[100];

ostrstream out(buf,sizeof(buf)) //opens output array,like cout but,
                                //writes the data to the array.

out << "Write text that will be written into buf\n";
out << "This will be attached";
out << ends; //ensures that buf is null-terminated
cout << buf;
return (0);
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a user-input with white-spaces you could use this code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(void) {

  string name;
  getline(cin, name);

  cout << name << endl;

  return (0x0);
}
```

And if you like to copy the data into an old cstring:

```
  char* old_cstr;
  old_cstr = new char[name.length() + 1];
  strcpy(old_cstr, name.c_str());
  cout << old_cstr << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I do this and all work. (first loop clear inputData- delete look like don't work)

```
int main(){
for(int i=0;i<99;i++){
::inputData[i]='\0';
}
//cin<<::inputData;
//char* tablica2= new char (strlen(inputData));


cout<<"how many words"<<endl;
int input;
cin>>input;
int temp=0;
int len=0;
char *tab1= new char[input];
for(int i=0;i<input;i++){
    cout<<" enter word "<<i+1<<endl;
    char* tem2= new char[20];
    cin>> tem2;
    strcat(::inputData,tem2);
    tab1[i]=*tem2;
    cout<<::inputData;
    len= len+ strlen(tem2);
    cout<<len;
//            if(len>strlen(::inputData)){
//              ::inputData= new char[(strlen(::inputData)*2)];
//        }
}
}
```